# 'HTML Agility Pack' XPath query with logical AND

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to find a table in a HTML document with the first 2 rows containing 3 columns with text in.

I have experimented trying to use the following query, which I want to return the  node that has the first 2 rows of the table contain text in the first column:

```
string xpath = @"//table//table[//tr[1]//td[1]//*[contains(text(), *)] and //tr[2]//td[1]//*[contains(text(), *)]]";
HtmlNode temp = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
```

It doesn't work properly, mon.

Here is some sample HTML, which is the table I'm trying to match:

```
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" border="0">
       <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td width="27%" valign="center"><b><font size="1" face="Helvetica">SOME TEXT<br></font></b></td>
          <td width="1%"></td>
          <td width="9%" valign="center"><font size="1" face="Helvetica">SOME TEXT<br></font></td>
          <td width="1%"></td>
          <td width="25%" valign="center"><font size="1" face="Helvetica">SOME TEXT<br></font></td>
          <td width="37%"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td valign="center"><font size="1" face="Helvetica">SOME TEXT<br></font></td>
          <td></td>
          <td valign="center"><font size="1" face="Helvetica">1<br></font></td>
          <td></td>
          <td valign="center"><font size="1" face="Helvetica">SOME TEXT<br></font></td>
          <td></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody>
</table>
```

You notice the columns 1,3,5 have text in the first 2 rows.  That's what I'm trying to match.

Comment: It would help a lot if you edit your question and insert the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//table//table[//tr[1]//td[1]//*[contains(text(), *)] and //tr[2]//td[1]//*[contains(text(), *)]]
```

**There are *many* problems with this XPath expression**:

1. `//table//table` selects any `table` that is a descendant of a `table`. However, in the provided XML document there are no nested tables.
2. `table[//tr[1]//td[1]//*[contains(text(), *)]` . The `//tr` inside the predicate is an *absolute* Xpath expression -- it selects all `tr` elements in the *whole document* -- not only in the subtree rooted by this `table` element. Most probably you want `.//tr` instead of `//tr`.
3. `//td[1]` selects any `td` element that is the first `td` child of its parent -- but most probably you want only the first descendant `td` element. If so, you need to use this XPath expression: `(//td)[1]`
4. `//*[contains(text(), *)]` this selects any element whose first text node child contains the string value of the first element child -- but you simply want to verify that a `td` has a descendant text child node -- this can correctly be selected with: `td[.//text()]`

**Combining the corrections of all these issues, what you probably want is something like**:

```
  //table
     [(.//tr)[1]/td[1][.//text()]
    and
      (.//tr)[2]/td[1][.//text()]
     ]
```

**Alternatively, one could write an equivalent but more understandable and less error-prone expression like this:**

```
//table
  [descendant::tr[1]/td[1][descendant::text()]
 and
   descendant::tr[1]/td[1][descendant::text()]
  ]
```

Comment: `string xpath = @"//table[(.//tr)[1]/td[1][.//text()] and (.//tr[2]/td[1][.//text()]]";
HtmlNodeCollection collection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);`

This throws an 'invalid token' exception.  I don't know if the XPath syntax used in the 'HTML Agility Pack' is slightly different or something, because I have noticed similar things happening with some of the XPath tutorials I have followed.  It also throws the same exception with merely `string xpath = @"//table//table//(.//tr)`.

Comment: @xM00x, It is quite possible that HAP doesn't implement the standard XPath language. Was the second expression evaluated successfully?

Comment: Works like a charm.  I kissed your photo.

Comment: *Of course, I meant: `string xpath = @"//table//table(.//tr)"`.